# JavaScript can toFixed() not cut everything after it's a specific size?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make this toFixed() number to cut the number to 3 last digits, but also i want to show its e *i mean it's 10^number*

like if i put 0.1 to Number 1, it shows **2.204e-7** insted of **0.000** in number 2

html:

```
<h4>number 1</h4>
<input type="number" id="num1" oninput="myFunc()">
<h5 id="real"></h5>

<br>

<h4>number 2</h4>
 <input type="number" id="num2">
```

javascript:

```
function myFunc(){
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");

  num2.value = num1.value * 0.00000220462;
  document.getElementById("real").innerHTML = "real value is: " + num2.value;

  if(num1.value.toString().includes("0.") | num1.value.toString().startsWith(".")){

    num2.value = Number.parseFloat(num2.value).toFixed(3);

  }
}
```

check this link: https://codepen.io/RawandHr/pen/ZEYaONw

Comment: What would you like it to show when you put 0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `toExponential()` instead of `toFixed()`.